# Can I remove the dark skin under my eyes

Tags: dermatology, coloration-discoloration, removal, pigment, periorbital-dark-circles

I think I have hey fever, which makes my eyes water uncontrollably and constantly.

This has happened since I was a child. I've been known to randomly cry, my friends know I'm not actually.

Instead of just letting the tears flow down, ill wipe them. I'll do this quite regularly, every few minutes or so, as soon as I feel liquid gathering.

I believe this wiping of salty tears has contributed to the damaged skin I have under my eyes, especially because it's most noticeable under my right eye which waters much more, thus gets rubbed much more.

Its started to very much bother me lately, the skin looks dry and dark compared the rest of my face.

I've thought of getting some medication via a checkup with a GP that would finally liberate me of this problem.

Would the skin naturally develop its natural pigmentation, or is this more serious damage?

The skins often sore, from what I think is the saltiness.

What exactly should I do. I'd love to have proper even skin, and not have to constantly wipe my eyes.